# Terminating a terminal application when a term shows in bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

Is it possible to write a bash script which runs a python application until the ouput of the application shows a specified term and then closes the application?

Edit:
The output looks like this:

```
2017-11-11 14:21:27 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test54
2017-11-11 14:21:28 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test55
2017-11-11 14:21:29 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test56
2017-11-11 14:21:30 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test57
2017-11-11 14:21:31 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test58
2017-11-11 14:21:32 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test59
2017-11-11 14:21:33 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test60
2017-11-11 14:21:34 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test61
2017-11-11 14:21:35 LOG: 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test62
2017-11-11 14:21:35 SUCCESS : 192.168.0.1 - Administrator:Test62
```

It should close after SUCCESS shows up.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
for i in range(0,5001):
    print(i)
```

You can terminate it when it outputs `2500` like this:

```
stdbuf -oL python a.py | sed '/2500/q'
```

---

Note, this a bit dirty, you might receive a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(i)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

But if you want to kill the program anyway ...

---

Important note:

This won't work if the script is writing to stderr (like [logging.StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) does by default), or if it's handling BrokenPipeError. The former can be easily fixed with |& redirection, but in the latter case, kill -INT would work better.

Comment: Note this won't work if the script is writing to `stderr` (like [`logging.StreamHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) does by default), or if it's handling `BrokenPipeError`. The former can be easily fixed with `|&` redirection, but in the latter case, `kill -INT` would work better.

Comment: @randomir Sure. I should have mentioned that. Let me add your comment to my answer.